# Page Navigation for list of post

Tags: posts

After getting help from ghost toast... I am almost seeing the light of day with this issue. Using this code I have been able to have a query of post show. However I am unable to figure out how to code it to work with the navigation. Thanks Ghost!

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <p class="post-date">
            <span class="date-day"><?php the_time('j') ?></span>
            <span class="date-month"><?php the_time('M') ?></span>
        </p>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

 </div>
   <p class="metadata">Posted by <?php the_author() ?>.<?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' |     
', ''); ?></p>
    </div>


<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

      <?php
global $wp_query;

$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1' );

 $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

 echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

Comment: Define "navigation".

Comment: Adding to Rarst's, please add more details to your Questions, brief descriptions of your problems doesn't invite to thoughtful Answers. A guide to good questioning: [ask].

Comment: Navigation - As in Page Navigation meaning let's say six post to each page of post. six displaying on "1" then click to "2" for the next six post. Do you know what I mean or do I need to render an example?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links read that yet?

Comment: @GhostToast No I haven't thanks man, I was reading and researching here (http://digwp.com/2013/01/display-blog-posts-on-page-with-navigation/) This is the page I'm working on, built it sometime back (http://gods-image.com/news-2) The way I built the page the div that holds the main content des not expand. Lets just say 4 post to a page then have either a <Next> <Prev> link or numbered page nav to move on to the next set of post. It really doesnt matter if its next or prev or numbered... Question is my code above set up correctly to support that functionality? It's a custom query.

Comment: Your code doesn't show an entire loop. There is no `endwhile`, so that's hard to say. Also if you want *next* and *previous* take a look at these functions: `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` in the codex.

Comment: @GhostToast Yo Ghost, check my edit out above... Any Suggestions?

Comment: What is `$query`'s job later on? Why being defined later? I've seen this example code before. You're trying to get category 1?

Comment: @GhostToast Right, I got this example code from the codex you just gave me. I plugged it right into the code and tried to shape it to work with the query. I added $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1' ); in an attempt to have it work with the category, because when I clicked next or on a page number nothing happened lol... I think it has something to do with how my query is structured period. I think I need to add the pageinate in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about all the other custom stuff you're running in there. But looks like you have taken a few tutorials and maybe mashed them together. I think something simple like this might work for you, then you can add some bells and whistles or try for paged navigation later. This will get you regular old Previous and Next links, which you indicated would satisfy your needs for now:

```
<?php 
if(have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="blog-object">
            <h2 class="blog-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>

            <div class="blog-entry-meta">
                <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></small>
            </div>
            <?php the_content();?>
        </article>
    <?php 
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
<div class="navigation">
    <span class="older"><?php next_posts_link('« Older') ?></span>
    <span class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer »') ?></span> 
</div><!-- .navigation -->
```

Feel free to modify that to accomodate other elements you want, such as author meta.

Comment: using the above code How would I code php to display a certain number of post per page. Let's just say 4 post per page?

Comment: You can actually set default posts per page under Settings -> Reading -- simple to do it there if you're not rolling your own WP_Query. But if you are rolling your own, look at this: [Class Reference/WP Query « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Man I read the whole WP_Query two times man and nothing... I'm seeing the light of day but can't seem to figure out how to get the links with the page numbers to work. When I click on a page number it displays the same post. Doesnt carry over to the next set of post.

Comment: @EAMann Can you undelete my answer?